# ARM Cortex A8 Freescale i.MX515 still supported in 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, 12.04, arm

I want to buy a ARM based Netbook (Herkules eCafé Slim HD) with ARM Cortex A8 Freescale i.MX515.

The Netbook comes preinstalled with Ubuntu, I guess 10.04. Is this ARM Controller still supported in Precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I.MX#Linux)

> On the i.MX51 family, the reference user interface is Ubuntu. The last
>   Ubuntu version supported is 10.04.1 (still available on mirrors).
>   Ubuntu dropped the "official" i.MX51 family support since version
>   10.10

This is confirmed by the [citation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/MaverickReleaseNotes).

Looking at the [Ubuntu ARM Roadmap](http://odm.ubuntu.com/uhs/2011/Ubuntu%20ARM%20Roadmap.pdf) 12.04 official support is:

> Seventh release to be in April 2012 (12.04) will support the TI OMAP 3
>   BeagleBoard, and the TI OMAP 4 PandaBoard, Freescale iMX53 Quickstart
>   platform

Thus - again your iMX51 series is not officially supported.

You'll note that the [latest beta CD images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/beta-1/) contain a release for the iMX53 but not for the iMX51 series.

Thus - its your choice - try before you buy or look for a iMX53 ARM laptop instead.

Comment: I don't have iMX51 Hardware, but I want to buy one. But if the support was dropped in 10.10 I don't want to buy.

Comment: Hey Burli, I can tell you that there is a heavy amount of optimization done to the 10.04 image provided by Herkules, It's not a bad little unit but I understand your decision.